# Problems with CSS scrollbars in Safari

Tags: css, safari, scrollbar

I'm having an issue with a scrollbar that doesn't scroll. Here is my web page (still under construction): http://www.personal.psu.edu/pzb4/zacs/
CSS file is at http://www.personal.psu.edu/pzb4/zacs/css/screen.css
The scrollbars work fine when tested in Chrome and Firefox. Safari seems to be the problem. When I click on the Depth of Field link, the scrollbar is inactive for some reason. I was having the same problem with the Exposure link, but once I fiddled with that and somehow got it working, the Depth of Field scrollbar stopped working! I didn't do anything to change that and it was working before. Scratching my head as to why this doesn't work right. Any help humbly appreciated.

Comment: My Safari has scrollbars. Are you using Safari for Mac or Windows?

Comment: I'm using a Mac. It does have scrollbars, but on the Depth of Field link the scrollbar does not function. It does on the others.

Comment: I think i'm closing in on it. it has to do with the positioning i had on it. still need to dial it in, but it seems to be functioning even though it's not quite in the right place.

Comment: oddly enough I can get it to function if the text area is 5 pixels to the left of where the other ones are for the other links. but that's not a good place for it. needs to be centered in the white area like the others. I also have to select the scrollbar just to the left of it on its hairline border to be able to move it. it now works 4 pixels to the left of where it's supposed to be. might be easier to just change the graphic behind it.